# python literal binary to hex conversion

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have a textfile containing a range of bits, in ascii:

```
cat myFile.txt
0101111011100011001...
```

I would like to write this to an other file in binary mode, so that i can read it in an hexeditor. How could I reach that? I tried already to convert it with code like:

```
f2=open(fileOut, 'wb')
    with open(fileIn) as f:
      while True:
            c = f.read(1)
            byte = byte+str(c)
            if not c:
                print "End of file"
                break
            if count % 8 is 0:
                count = 0 
                print hex(int(byte,2))
                try:
                    f2.write('\\x'+hex(int(byte,2))[2:]).zfill(2)
                except:
                     pass
                byte = ''
            count += 1
```

but that didn't achieve what I planed to do. Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
import struct
...
f2.write(struct.pack('b', int(byte,2))) # signed 8 bit int
```

or

```
f2.write(struct.pack('B', int(byte,2))) # unsigned 8 bit int
```

Answer (score 2):

- Reading and writing one byte at a time is painfully slow. You may get around ~45x speedup of your code simply by reading more data from the file per call to `f.read` and `f.write`:

  ```
  |------------------+--------------------|
  | using_loop_20480 | 8.34 msec per loop | 
  | using_loop_8     | 354 msec per loop  |
  |------------------+--------------------|
  ```

  `using_loop` is the code shown at the bottom of this post. `using_loop_20480` is the code with chunksize = 1024*20. This means that 20480 bytes are read from the file at a time. `using_loop_1` is the same code with chunksize = 1.
- Regarding `count % 8 is 0`: Don't use `is` to compare numerical values; use `==`  instead. Here are some examples why `is` may give you wrong results (maybe not in the code you posted, but in general, `is` is not appropriate here):

  ```
  In [5]: 1L is 1
  Out[5]: False

  In [6]: 1L == 1
  Out[6]: True

  In [7]: 0.0 is 0
  Out[7]: False

  In [8]: 0.0 == 0
  Out[8]: True
  ```
- Instead of

  ```
  struct.pack('{n}B'.format(n = len(bytes)), *bytes)
  ```

  you could use

  ```
  bytearray(bytes)
  ```

  Not only is it less typing, it is a slight bit faster too.

  ```
  |------------------------------+--------------------|
  |             using_loop_20480 | 8.34 msec per loop |
  | using_loop_with_struct_20480 | 8.59 msec per loop |
  |------------------------------+--------------------|
  ```

  [bytearrays](http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html) are a good match for this job because it bridges the
  gap between regarding the data as a string and as a sequence of
  numbers.

  ```
  In [16]: bytearray([97,98,99])
  Out[16]: bytearray(b'abc')

  In [17]: print(bytearray([97,98,99]))
  abc
  ```

  As you can see above, `bytearray(bytes)` allows you to
  define the bytearray by passing it a sequence of ints (in
  `range(256)`), and allows you to write it out as though it were a
  string: `g.write(bytearray(bytes))`.

---

```
def using_loop(output, chunksize):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f, open(output, 'wb') as g:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunksize)
            if chunk == '':
                break
            bytes = [int(chunk[i:i+8], 2)
                     for i in range(0, len(chunk), 8)]
            g.write(bytearray(bytes))
```

Make sure chunksize is a multiple of 8.

---

This is the code I used to create the tables. Note that [prettytable](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) also does something similar to this, and it may be advisable to use their code rather than my hack: [table.py](https://gist.github.com/4330910)

This is the module I used to time the code: [utils_timeit.py](https://gist.github.com/4330933). (It uses table.py).

And here is the code I used to time `using_loop` (and other variants): [timeit_bytearray_vs_struct.py](https://gist.github.com/4330943)

Comment: I like your tables, what's your timing setup?

Comment: @Kos: I've edited my post with gist links to the code I used. I am sorry it is so much code, and not really ready for publication.

Comment: Thanks! ([2] and [3] refer to the same link, probably a typo.) I kind of hoped that `timeit` has this built-in somewhere ;-) Your hack seems to auto-detect column widths and I'm not sure if `prettytable` also does that. I kind of remember looking for it and ending up writing it myself, but I can't really remember whether that was about `texttable` or `prettytable` package.

Comment: @Kos: Thanks for pointing out the broken link (now fixed). Its too bad we've all written our own code for this. We need one Table to rule them all. :)